# Should I use clusterServersConfig or replicatedServersConfig when using AWS Elasticache on Redisson?

Tags: redis, redisson, amazon-elasticache

I am using a clustered Redis with replicas.  With Redisson I am getting this randomly

> org.redisson.client.RedisException: MOVED redirection loop detected. Node redis://10.92.231.18:6379 has further redirect to redis://10.92.231.18:6379

Should I be using `replicatedServersConfig` in that situation?